# Why does Gradle's javaexec behave differently from running Java directly?

Tags: gradle, openapi-generator

I am trying to integrate the generation of REST-API client code via the openapi-generator through Gradle. Using the openapi-generator-gradle-plugin at first, I found some bugs that make it impossible to achieve what I want, so I thought I might just download the JAR of the openapi-generator-cli in order to define a Gradle task with `javaExec` that will execute the generator for me.

The task looks is defined as:

build.gradle.kts

```
task("generate") {
    javaexec {
        main = "-jar"
        args = listOf(
            "$rootDir\\openapi-generator-cli.jar",
            "generate",
            "--skip-validate-spec",
            "-g kotlin",
            "-i $rootDir\\spec\\api.yml",
            "-o $rootDir\\lib",
            "-c $rootDir\\generate-kotlin.json"
        )
    }
}
```

However, when running the `generate` task, execution fails with

```
C:\work\kotlin\myapi\generate-kotlin.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

This is where things get strange, as I can see no issue with the path to the file in question.

I then activated debugging output for the task to see the actual command executed by Gradle. It is (formatted for readability):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe ^
-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 ^
-Duser.country=DE ^
-Duser.language=de ^
-Duser.variant ^
-jar C:\work\kotlin\myapi\openapi-generator-cli.jar generate ^
--skip-validate-spec ^
-g kotlin ^
-i C:\work\kotlin\myapi\spec\api.yml ^
-o C:\work\kotlin\myapi\lib ^
-c C:\work\kotlin\myapi\generate-kotlin.json
```

To me, everything looks perfectly fine in that command. To test, I copy-pasted it to a CMD and it ran right away without any errors.

Despite the question being a bit centered around openapi-generator, as I can run the command perfectly fine manually, I assume this to be a problem with Gradle and would really like to know why it is receiving this error when the command it runs has no issues whatsoever?

I really don't want to write command-line scripts for people to execute when I could let Gradle do what I want to do.

Comment: When you copy-paste to CMD window, is there a value set for the `CLASSPATH` environment variable?

Comment: @MichaelEaster Just checked, CLASSPATH is unset in the CMD. Not quite sure how that would affect any absolute paths, but then again, I don't have too much knowledge about this particular topic